# How can I left-justify text in centered math mode?

Tags: math-mode, formatting

If I want to achieve something like the following:

[image]

where the text before the equaions is left-justified, how can I do that? So far I've been using stuff like

```
\llap{ Which gives us \hspace{3cm}} f;g;h = fg;h = fgh = f;gh
```

where I have to tweak the amount of hspace each time. I'm often, but not always, doing this inside the `gather` environment.

I suppose I could make an array with `lcc` columns, and put some `\hfill` in the left column, but how do I tell it to center the line on the middle column?

Comment: The `\hspace{3cm}`within `\rlap` does nothing. Try an `flalign` environment, with the text in the first column, and the math alignment in the middle column. But why don't you simply use `\(short)intertext`?

Comment: often in a situation like this, `\intertext` is used (or `\shortintertext` from `mathtools`).  of course, that puts the text on a separate line.

Comment: @Bernard Sorry, I met `\llap`. Is there a way not to put the text on a separate line?

Comment: `\llap` should be used only at the right margin.

Comment: @Bernard Why not?

Comment: @Eric Auld: I mean it shouldn't be used at the left margin, unless you want to write in the left margin. For the same reason`\rlap` shouldn't be used at the right margin – it creates a left-aligned box of width 0pt, so that its contents is written in the right margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `flalign*`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} %
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
&  & f; gh &  = f\,gh  &  &\llap{from side  $ (0,1,3) $} \\
&  & f; g &  = gh &  &\llap{from side  $ (0,1,2) $} \\
&\rlap{Which gives us}  & f; g; h = f\,g; h &  = f\,gh  =  f; gh \\
&\rlap{And inverting  $ f $  gives us}  &    g; h &  = gh &  & 
\end{flalign*}    

\end{document}
```

[image]